# Is it possible to construct dynamic aggregate columns in an ARel query that uses a join?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Here's a bit of sample context for my question below to help clarify what I'm asking...

**The Schema**

```
Users
- id
- name

Answers
- id
- user_id
- topic_id
- was_correct

Topics
- id
- name
```

**The Data**

```
Users
id | name
1  | Gabe
2  | John

Topics
id | name
1  | Math
2  | English

Answers 
id | user_id | topic_id | was_correct
 1 |       1 |        1 | 0
 2 |       1 |        1 | 1
 3 |       1 |        2 | 1
 4 |       2 |        1 | 0
 5 |       2 |        2 | 0
```

What I'd like to have, in a result set, is a table with one row per user, and two columns per topic, one that shows the sum of correct answers for the topic, and one that shows the sum of the incorrect answers for that topic. For the sample data above, this result set would look like:

**My desired result**

```
users.id | users.name | topic_1_correct_sum | topic_1_incorrect_sum | topic_2_correct_sum | topic_2_incorrect_sum
       1 | Gabe       | 1                   | 1                     | 1                   | 0
       2 | John       | 0                   | 1                     | 0                   | 1
```

Obviously, if there were more topics in the Topics table, I'd like this query to include new correct_sum and incorrect_sums for each topic that exists, so I'm looking for a way to write this without hard-coding topic_ids into the sum functions of my select clause.

**Is there a smart way to magic this sort of thing with ARel?**

Answer (score 0):

Gabe,

What you're looking for here is a crosstab query. There are many approaches to writing this, unfortunately none that will be generic enough in SQL. AFAIK each database handles crosstabs differently. Another way of looking at this is as a "cube", something typically found in OLAP-type databases (as opposed to OLTP).

Its easily writeable in SQL, however will likely include some functions native to the database you're using. What DB are you using?

Your answers table looks like it needs to have 1,2,3,4,5 and not 1,1,1,1,1 as ids...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Steven.  In my case, I'm using Postgresql, and I've got the query I need already written in SQL, it's just icky sql that I don't love and was hoping to see, mostly for my edification, if ARel can help me do this in Rails 3.